# Generic Computation of Distance Matrices in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, linear-algebra, array-broadcasting

I have two tensors `a` & `b` of shape `(m,n)`, and I would like to compute a distance matrix `m` using some distance metric `d`. That is, I want `m[i][j] = d(a[i], b[j])`. This is somewhat like `cdist(a,b)` but assuming a generic distance function `d` which is not necessarily a p-norm distance. Is there a generic way to implement this in PyTorch?

And a more specific side question: Is there an efficient way to perform this with the following metric

```
d(x,y) = 1 - cos(x,y)
```

**edit**

I've solved the specific case above using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411191/how-to-compute-the-cosine-similarity-in-pytorch-for-all-rows-in-a-matrix-with-re) answer:

```
def metric(a, b, eps=1e-8):
    a_norm, b_norm = a.norm(dim=1)[:, None], b.norm(dim=1)[:, None]
    a_norm = a / torch.max(a_norm, eps * torch.ones_like(a_norm))
    b_norm = b / torch.max(b_norm, eps * torch.ones_like(b_norm))
    similarity_matrix = torch.mm(a_norm, b_norm.transpose(0, 1))
    return 1 - similarity_matrix
```

Comment: There's no such function that I'm aware of. Please attach some code, did you try to implement it?

Comment: I have no idea how to start. I've solved the smaller question based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411191/how-to-compute-the-cosine-similarity-in-pytorch-for-all-rows-in-a-matrix-with-re) answer. I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using broadcasting: since `a,b` both have shape `(m,n)` you can compute

```
m = d( a[None, :, :], b[:, None, :])
```

where `d` needs to operate on the last dimension, so for instance

```
def d(a,b): return 1 - (a * b).sum(dim=2) / a.pow(2).sum(dim=2).sqrt() / b.pow(2).sum(dim=2).sqrt()
```

(here I assume that `cos(x,y)` represents the normalized inner product between `x` and `y`)